# How to use fetch='join' in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I encountered a problem on usering Hibernate. Table A one-to-one Table B and Table A one-to-one Table C.Now I use the method get(A.class, id), but Hibernate generate two sql:the first one a join b, the second is "select c" when use the property c in a, That is fetch="join" is fail in a and c, Who can help me find the reason？

Comment: Can you please provided your code example? We need to see your mappings.

Comment: And the exception stack trace

Comment: Not sure he (or she) is seeing an exception, just 2 sql statements. :-)

Comment: <one-to-one name="userInfo"
    class="com.ultrapower.pasm.app.account.model.UserInfo" cascade="all"
    constrained="true" fetch="join" />

   <one-to-one name="userPolicy"
    class="com.ultrapower.pasm.app.account.model.UserPolicy" cascade="all"
    constrained="true" fetch="join"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
from Cat as cat
inner join cat.mate as mate
left outer join cat.kittens as kitten
```

More examples [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)